# How to get matplotlib (pyplot) plots to update in loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've read a bunch of similar posts, but nothing is working.  I have a loop and am attempting to update 3 figures containing images with text overlays, kind of like this:

```
def updatePlot(data, fig):
  fig.clear()
  ax = fig.subplots()
  ax.imshow(...)
  ax.text(...)
  plt.show()
  plt.draw()
  plt.pause(0.0001)

fig1 = plt.figure()
fig2 = plt.figure()
fig3 = plt.figure()

while True:
  # do computation
  updatePlot(..., fig1)
  updatePlot(..., fig2)
  updatePlot(..., fig3)
```

The symptom is that only fig3 updates and the others stay static until I kill the program, then they refresh.  I'm working in an ipython terminal (in Spyder).

Comment: You might want to take a look at [animations](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html). Also try adding a longer pause, `0.0001` might just be too short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work. It's running in interactive mode (`plt.ion()`) and flushes the events on each figure.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()

def updatePlot(data, fig):
  fig.clear()
  ax = fig.subplots()
  ax.imshow(data)
  ax.text(2,2, np.mean(data))

  plt.pause(0.1)
  fig.canvas.draw_idle()
  fig.canvas.flush_events()

fig1 = plt.figure()
fig2 = plt.figure()
fig3 = plt.figure()

while True:
  # do computation
  updatePlot(np.random.rand(4,4), fig1)
  updatePlot(np.random.rand(6,6), fig2)
  updatePlot(np.random.rand(10,10), fig3)
```

This is pretty unstable and inefficient though. Maybe consider using `FuncAnimation`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def updatePlot(data, image, text):
    image.set_data(data)
    text.set_text(data.mean())

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
image1 = ax1.imshow(np.random.rand(4,4))
text1 = ax1.text(2,2, "")

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
image2 = ax2.imshow(np.random.rand(6,6))
text2 = ax2.text(2,2, "")

fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()
text3 = ax3.text(2,2, "")
image3 = ax3.imshow(np.random.rand(10,10))

def update_plots(i):
    # do computation
    updatePlot(np.random.rand(4,4), image1, text1)
    updatePlot(np.random.rand(6,6), image2, text2)
    updatePlot(np.random.rand(10,10), image3, text3)
    fig2.canvas.draw_idle()
    fig3.canvas.draw_idle()

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update_plots, interval=40)

plt.show()
```